# Intuition of probability multiplication rule

Tags: probability, combinatorics, intuition

What do you think of probability as?

I sometimes think of it as : favorable/total outcomes.
But I can tell it doesn't always work for me.

Ex- Suppose we are tossing a coin, and we keep tossing until we get a head.
So what's the prob of getting a head within, say 10 times? ---case 1

So in this kind of problems, I use product rule of probability.

Suddenly today, I'm wondering about its intuition.
As I think, suppose, the events are independent.
Ex: suppose an event A about dice (example getting an even or prime number)
so let p be the prob of getting A in each throw of a dice for k times, and if I wanted to find out for k+1 throws.

so I think of it as: k*p times of the throws, I get event A happened all the k times,

so p(A) for k+1 throws = (p*k*4)/(k*6) = p*p(A in one throw)

This is what I visualize product rule as.
But this too gets quite non-intuitive, when p*k is non-integer and also gets non-intuitive in case 1 kinda things.

Like I have a pretty good intuition of things, but it's still questioning inside.

Tell me all the ways you think of product rule and probability as.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B\mid A)$.  In the case that $B$ and $A$ happen to be independent events that simplifies as $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$.  This follows immediately from the definition of conditional probability and the definition of independent events.

Comment: You might want to look at a good text on probability theory; one of my favourites is K. L Chung, "[Elementary Probability Theory with Stochastic Processes](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Elementary_Probability_Theory_with_Stoch/hDnnBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)"